# The H264 Codec in Premiere Pro CS6 Creates MP4 Files with Variable Frame Rates

Tags: premiere

I am trying to export my project and sequence to the final video format for distribution, which ideally would be H.264, however, after reviewing the resulting MP4 video in MediaInfo, I am concerned that it exhibits a Variable Frame Rate.  The variables being Min 29.97fps and Max 30fps.  To my knowledge most film distributors require video submissions to have a constant frame rate, and yes, I realize I could use Handbrake to achieve this in post production, but I would like to know if this is how all H.264 codecs currently process video with VFR.  I say this, because I have some older MP4 videos that I previously created through PP CS5, and they are reported to have a constant frame rate by MediaInfo. Yet, all my exports to H.264 from PP CS6 have a Variable Frame Rate.  Any help would be appreciated, I have been experimenting with all of this for 5 weeks and I can't afford any more time being lost.  Thank you